# Running dask scheduler from Python code with GUI

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

For a reason specific to my build system I cannot currently run dask-scheduler CLI - I have to start scheduler from code (example is provided in dask.distributed documentation). Is there also a way to start and customize (i.e. choose port) the Web GUI for the scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting up the scheduler you can pass a `services=` keyword

```
from distributed.scheduler import Scheduler
from distributed.bokeh.scheduler import BokehScheduler

scheduler = Scheduler(..., services={('bokeh', 8787): BokehScheduler})
```